# Where can I code in C?

Tags: c

I have an upcoming CS course in uni that uses C and I want to get ahead a little bit this Christmas break but I'm having a hard time figuring out where I can actually code using C. My school uses this compiler called Seashell but it's not available until the term starts.

I've looked at visual studio but I only see C++, and I've heard of stuff like Vim, GCC, but I'm pretty new to CS and I don't know what any of that really means...

Help?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! It might be a surprise to you, but your question is off-topic here. We deal with computer *science* questions, not programming questions. Please see our [help on topic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your question might be on-topic on [SO].

Comment: I'm sorry, but this kind of question is not appropriate for CS.SE (this site) or StackOverflow. Those sites seek precise questions with definite, objective answers -- they are not discussion forums, but Q&A sites.

Answer (score 1):

**Visual Studio Code**
Supports many languages including C/C++. It's a very simple IDE. Have a look at it.
https://code.visualstudio.com/

Answer (score 0):

The fifty-year-old C compiler is included with Linux operating systems. The C compiler was also ported to Windows as part of a legal agreement.

Here is a link:

https://gcc.gnu.org/

Now I see the comments so this subject might be a "Software Recommendation".